# Output redirection to console in shell script , not reflecting realtime

Tags: shell

I have encountered a weird problem with console output when calling a subscript from inside another script.
Below is the Main Script which is calling a TestScript.
The TestScript is an installation script written in perl which takes some time to execute and prints messages as the installation progresses.
My problem here is that the output from the called perl script is only shown on the console once the installation is completed and the script returns.

Oddly i have used this kind of syntax successfully before for calling shell scripts and it works fine for them and output is shown simultaneously without waiting for the subscript to return.

I need to capture the output of the script so that i can grep if the installation was successful.
I do not control the perl script and cannot modify it in any way.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo " Main script"
output=`/var/tmp/Packages/TestScript.pl | tee /dev/tty`
exitCode=$?
echo $output | grep -q "Installation completed successfully"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Installation was successful"
fi

echo $exitCode
```

Comment: (1) Does it help to make the STDOUT of TestScript.pl unbuffered? (2) What happens if you do not use `timeout` when running the test? *timeout* runs the command in a subshell and I guess it collects the output before passing it on, so buffering could occur here as well. IMO, it would make more sense to control the whole pipe by `timeout`, and not just the installation command. (3) Why are you introducing another subprocess  (`bash -c) here? It is unnecessary. You can directly call your TestScript.pl (I assume this is a Perl program).

Comment: 1) How can i make the stdout of TestScript.pl unbuffered from here , i cannot modify the TestScript since it is not mine.
2) If i do not use timeout , it does not work either . It only works if i do not try to capture the output in a variable using backticks.
3) The subprocess bash -c was required as a workaround so that i could use the pipe with timeout , otherwise the | tee /dev/tty would not let the timeout work.

Comment: I have modified the script in the question so that we have timeout and bash -c related concerns out of the way.
Please check the modified script in the original question.

Comment: If TestScript.pl is doing the buffering and you must not modify it, then you really have to use dirty tricks, but it would be unusual that an installation program, which reports the progress of the installation, would do it buffered, so first I would verify whether *tee* could be the culprit; maybe it collects the lines before outputting them. What happens if you don't use any backticks and no *tee*, and just run TestScript.pl? Do you still see the buffering?

Comment: It just occured to me, that it won't help for a test running TestScript.pl just without backticks, because, if the program really writes to STDOUT without changing the default settings, Perl would decided by itself on the buffering: If STDOUT is redirected to a file or a pipe, it would be *fully buffered*. If it is connected to a TTY / Console, it runs in a mode called *line buffered*, which means that the buffer is flushed after each of those `print` statements which output a newline; so, before we can decide further, have a look at the Perl code, how it does buffering.

Comment: If the Perl-Program doesn't modify the buffering behaviour, we have a chance to trick it out, but first we should verify what it is really doing.